# How do I alias a column name in a for loop?

Tags: r

I'm making a function and I'd like to call a column in a particular way.

**Initialize data**

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
d <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
```

**Call column for the table function**

```
Func <- function(df){
  X <- df
  Y <- names(M)

  for(i in 1:2){ 
    table(X$___,X$___)
}}
```

The trouble is I don't know how to call the columns.

I'd like it to be the equivalent to `table(X$a, X$b)` as it iterates through the loop.

**I tried this and it didn't work**

```
  for(i in 1:2){ 
        Q <- Y[i]
        W <- Y[j]
        table(X$Q,X$W)
}}
```

It is necessary for a function I'm using that I make a table with the form `table(X$a, X$b)` and I don't know quite how to achieve that in a for loop?

Comment: What is the `for` loop for? You could do `table(df[1:2])` instead of `table(X$a, X$b)`.

Comment: that's it! thanks ronak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `table` using names of the column you could use column index and use it in the function so you don't have to worry about how to call the columns.

Replace your `for` loop and use

```
table(df[1:2])
```

which would give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two `[[` to get the content of the column:

```
 df <- datasets::mtcars
 for (i in 1:2) df[[i]]
```

This will also work for column names

```
for (i in names(df)) df[[i]]
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve though. You can also just do:

```
lapply(df[1:2], table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop through `col` using column index. In the following code you can loop through `iris` dataset column:

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(iris))){
  print(iris[,i]) # to get single column
  print(iris[,c(i,i+1)]) # to get multiple column data
}
```